# Создание 2 таблиц в одном db файле sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

В своём проекте я использую db.Model для работы с базой данных, вид кода выходит соответствующий:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:///clients.db"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
class Clients(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
```

Сейчас у меня появилась задача, в которой мне придётся использовать в базе данных несколько таблиц. Я нашёл в интернете варианты с metadata, но я не понимаю, как их связать с уже существующей базой данных. Можете, пожалуйста, подсказать, как создать новую таблицу в том же db файле без использования metadata **или** с её использованием, но так же с описанием, как всё связать. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Также как были созданы Clients. Отнаследоваться от db.Model. Дальше или создаём всё через db.create_all() или как тут https://stackoverflow.com/a/41031434/7753445 только определённую таблицу.

Comment: Большое спасибо, разобрался. Всё оказалось очевидно)